# Using Powershell to copy and replace content from one file to another

Tags: powershell

I have two files: FileA and FileB, they are nearly identical.

Both files have a section which starts with `////////// MAIN \\\\\\\\\\`. I need to replace the whole content from this point until the end of the file.

So the process high level looks like:

1. find content (starting with `////////// MAIN \\\\\\\\\\`) until the end of the file in FileA and copy it to clipboard
2. find content (starting with `////////// MAIN \\\\\\\\\\`) until the end of the file in FileB and replace it with the content from the clipboard

How do I do this?

I understand that it would look like this (found it online) but I'm missing the pattern and logic I can use for selecting the text until the end of the file:

```
# FileA
$inputFileA = "C:\fileA.txt"
# Text to be inserted
$inputFileB = "C:\fileB.txt"
# Output file
$outputFile = "C:\fileC.txt"
# Find where the last </location> tag is
if ((Select-String -Pattern "\</location\>" -Path $inputFileA |
    select -last 1) -match ":(\d+):")
{
    $insertPoint = $Matches[1]
    # Build up the output from the various parts
    Get-Content -Path $inputFileA | select -First $insertPoint | Out-File $outputFile
    Get-Content -Path $inputFileB | Out-File $outputFile -Append
    Get-Content -Path $inputFileA | select -Skip $insertPoint | Out-File $outputFile -Append
}
```

Comment: How large are these files? Will they both fit in memory?

Comment: Hi Theo, they are not very long, maybe 10k lines (I assume this is not very long :-)

Maybe 100-200kb in size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that in two lines of code:

```
# first write the top part including the '////////// MAIN \\\\\\\\\\' from FileB to the new file
((Get-Content -Path "D:\Test\fileB.txt" -Raw) -split '(?<=/+ MAIN \\+\r?\n)', 2)[0]  | Set-Content -Path "D:\Test\fileC.txt" -NoNewline
# then append the bottom part excluding the '////////// MAIN \\\\\\\\\\' from FileA to the new file
((Get-Content -Path "D:\Test\fileA.txt" -Raw) -split '/+ MAIN \\+\r?\n', 2)[-1]      | Add-Content -Path "D:\Test\fileC.txt"
```

Regex details:

```
(?<=         # Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind)
   /         # Match the character “/” literally
      +      # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   \ MAIN\   # Match the characters “ MAIN ” literally
   \\        # Match the character “\” literally
      +      # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   \r        # Match a carriage return character
      ?      # Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   \n        # Match a line feed character
)
```

Or, if the files are quite large:

```
# first write the top part including the '////////// MAIN \\\\\\\\\\' from FileB to the new file
$copyThis = $true
$content = switch -Regex -File "D:\Test\fileB.txt" {
    '/+ MAIN \\+'  { $copyThis = $false; $_ ; break}
    default { if ($copyThis) { $_ } }
}
$content | Set-Content -Path "D:\Test\fileC.txt"

# then append the bottom part excluding the '////////// MAIN \\\\\\\\\\' from FileA to the new file
$copyThis = $false
$content = switch -Regex -File "D:\Test\fileA.txt" {
    '/+ MAIN \\+'  { $copyThis = $true }
    default { if ($copyThis) { $_ } }
}
$content | Add-Content -Path "D:\Test\fileC.txt"
```

Comment: Oh wow! That worked like a charm, thanks a lot sir, really jealous about your regex skills here. Thanks!